# Cannot get new computer to connect to domain

Tags: windows

Windows server essential connector, cannot get new computer to connect to domain, states server unavailable.

I have made sure server and client have correct synced time, updates are current on both machines

Note: Task tray has a yellow triangle on network connection indicating no connection, I can connect to all network shares and I can also connect to the internet. I can also RDP into server from another location.

Comment: Does DNS work? Or do you only connect with the IP address all the time?

Comment: DNS is working, I can ping the FQDN within command prompt

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be worth adding some more information if the below fix does not work.

While I have not used the Windows server essential connector before, I have experienced something similar while trying a regular domain join.

The yellow triangle on the workstation (assuming it’s on the, but regardless) is controlled by Network Location Awareness service, which uses two elements. The Network Location Awareness (NLA) and Network Connection Status Indicator (NCSI) to determine your network connectivity.

You can read up more on the two here

NLA - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc753545(v=ws.10)

NCSI - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2012/12/20/the-network-connection-status-icon/

It will take trial and error to learn which is causing the triangle, and therefore your domain joining issue (assuming the two are linked)

To determine if NLA is the cause, try disabling the windows firewall (temporally as it should get a domain setting regarding the firewall settings once connected) or restart the Network Location Awareness service.

If you think NCSI is at play, double check your local DNS setting. It maybe caused by the workstation not having a local DNS server to use hence why it cannot connect to the domain (some more info would help rule out or confirm the validity of the assumption)

Comment: I checked out NLA as this service would not start, so I looked at the logon info and it was using a different account, so it wouldnt talk to the NCSI service to allow it to start. I changed logon info and it cleared up yellow triangle issue. I will see if new computer will join once I get on site, unable to do it remotely. Thank you for the tip. But I am getting reports from users that other domain joined workstations are giving them an error of Trust issue connecting workstation to primary domain, not sure if the two issues here are related or if its a DNS issue. Thank you for your input

Comment: Hi Phil, glad I could add some value. Let me know how you get on (I am invested now :) )